# Confused about 'badge' in push

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

Well after a marathon session, push started working in my app. Had to totally re-create certs from scratch a second time, and then *poof*, there it was.

But one problem we found was the use of 'badge' on the production server. If we remove it we get notifications, when we add it we don't. That seems very odd, it seems totally orthogonal.

Is there something that happens client-side when 'badge' is present that would stop delivery? I believe the server sent 'badge=>1', whatever that means (I'm strictly client-side).

Comment: What do you mean by "remove badge"? Your notifications are delivered only when the badge key is not present? Could you provide an example of your payload?

Comment: Correct, when we removed it it suddenly worked. The payload is...    'alert' => 'My push message!'
 'target' => 'xxx',
 'badge' => 1,
 'sound' => 'default'

Comment: This is no valid JSON payload, but I guess that you have some mechanism to translate it (on your server). Could you post two complete examples in JSON format (one without badge, one with)?

Answer (score 0):

If your server really sent the badge in the JSON String as `badge=>1`, it's invalid, and may have caused the notification to be discarded.

The correct format of the badge in the JSON String should be `"badge" : 1`.

It's possible, though, that your server translates `badge=>1` to `"badge" : 1`, so perhaps that's not the problem.

Comment: I can test this, I have a little test harness... but it raises the question, which I did *not* see in the Apple docs, if the badge is currently (some number I don't know) how does one increment it?

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz You increment it in the server and send the incremented number to the client.

Comment: so everyone keeps track of how many badges they sent in the past? How do they know when to reset it, when the app runs?